# What will happen if a mother with a small child travels in an airplane/airport and the mother will be hospitalized/unable to take care of the child?

Tags: airport-transfer, health, children, aircraft

I’m not sure who would take care of the child (1 year old) if a responsible parent will be unable to take care of the child due to health issues? Let’s say the parent will stay for 2 days in the hospital, who would take care of the child to be in a safe place? Or possibly informed husband in the home country to pick up a child, who will meanwhile assure the child is safe and cared?

Is there a special airport service for such cases or travel insurance company providing this?

Thank you.

Comment: In what country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What will happen if a mother with a small child travels by bus and is incapacitated, or is walking down the street, or watching a wrestling match? Regardless of the location, most countries with functional governments will have some kind of social services/child protection/child welfare agency responsible for caring for children left alone. Such care could take the form of emergency foster care or take place in the hospital until the mother was well enough or a responsible relative was able to travel and pick up the child.

Some large airports have social workers assigned (who may also assist in cases like stranded/destitute passengers) who might be part of helping with this process, but this would generally be more of a government service than one specific to the airport. Travel insurance doesn't usually cover emergency child care.

Answer (score 3):

As well as Zach Lipton's excellent answer,  some medical insurances will pay for a caregiver to fly out to look after the patient if they are taken ill. They may also provide for someone to fly out and take care of a dependent. They should provide for the child to be flown home where they can be cared for. Check your insurance, and buy one with this coverage if it is important.